# How to disable "Share Wi-Fi password" prompt

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, wifi, bluetooth

Every few minutes I keep getting the following prompt (on all 3 of my devices - my iMac, Macbook and iPhone):

**MacOS:**

[image: MacBook Share WiFi]

**iOS:**

[image: iPhone Share Wifi Message]

Even if I click "Decline" or "Share" it still shows up every few minutes on all my devices. How do I stop this from happening?

I asked the question in Apple Support but no one knows the answer there either: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251248798?

Comment: What can I add to my answer to make it more useful?

Comment: @bmike: Thank you for your answer but the problem still persists. I am hoping a bounty may attract another answer.

Comment: Sounds good. Great use, bounty brings fresh eyes.

Answer (score 3):

This happens in one specific circumstance:

1. Another device is within bluetooth distance of your Mac and both have Bluetooth on.
2. The other device is scanning for Wi-Fi
3. You and the other person are signed in to iCloud and they are in your contacts.

You can remove their contact, sign out of iCloud, turn off wireless / Bluetooth or share the password. They could sign out of iCloud, turn off Wireless / Bluetooth.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-a-wi-fi-password-on-mac-mchlp1179/mac

The share should send the password, but their device isn’t connecting, so escalate your steps or possibly vacate the area?

For iOS removing your contact from their contacts might do the trick as well.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209368

Worst case, your iCloud are not syncing identity records or her device needs other fixes. Tweaking these settings resolves the situation on machines without other problems.

- [Why we're not customer support for [company X or product Y]](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y)

If none of these help, working with Apple employees would be needed to look at why you can’t share between your two iCloud accounts. That prompt happens since your recipient keeps asking for the password and can’t share it. Focus on fixing the other machine and account is my advice if I understand your setup.

Comment: The other device is my wife's (Nastassia). I can't really remove her from my contacts nor vacate our area (our home) as much as I would love to.

Comment: I’ll add one last step, customer assistance from Apple. If yours and her iCloud aren’t syncing, that could cause this.

Comment: I did ask in Apple support forums - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251248798

Comment: That won’t help, you need an AppleCare engineer on the phone or 1:1 chat. No one here on on Apple discussions can see the server side details of your accounts, @pathikrit https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y

Comment: AppleCare made me sign out and restart and sign-in back to my iCloud. The prompt came back after few hours.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurred for me after installing UniFi Controller 5.14.23 for macOS on my MacBook running 10.15.6 Catalina. The issue occurred for both users on the MacBook and both iPhones (logged in to different iCloud accounts) on the wireless network.

The issue was resolved for me by removing the UniFi Controller and restarting the MacBook.

Comment: I also got this issue after adding a Ubiquiti Dreammachine Pro to my network with two Unify Acces points.